# Volunteering for events where there is free-mixing and designing a poster with a logo containing small shadow of a woman

Tags: halal-haram

(1) Is it permissible to volunteer as an event coordinator for the branch of IEEE WIE(Women In Engineering) in our university? There is free-mixing and the instructor of the workshops may be male or female. IEEE WIE promotes career for women in engineering. Note that I am a boy. References are needed from Quraan or Hadeeth.

(2) Is it permissible to design a poster for an event with the logo of this group which contains a shadow of a woman in the character W? Shadow means only a color, not like real image, and there are shadows of an eye lid, nose, and hair. The logo will remain such small that it is usually not noticed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) This is a professional event for work, education, and learning. In the workplace, you might have female co-workers you'll work with. As long as you're cautious of your deen, you should be fine. If you believe it is too much fitna for you then do not go.

2.) If you're worried about the Islamic opinion on the drawing of living things or drawings of things that can represent living things then it depends on your Islamic opinion on it.

A popular opinion is that the drawing of living things is haram. There are varying opinions on this issue.

There's another opinion according to the Maliki Fiqh that drawing living things is only makruh (disliked) but not haram.

https://seekersguidance.org/answers/maliki-fiqh/the-maliki-view-on-pictures-of-humans-and-animals/

[Why does the Maliki school of thought condone drawings of animated beings?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37480/why-does-the-maliki-school-of-thought-condone-drawings-of-animated-beings)

Other scholars considered the drawing of living things to be permissible as long as the drawing isn't something haram or meant to be used for haram (such as worshipping, etc).

Sheikh Yusuf-Al-Qaradawi's fatwa in Arabic regarding the drawing of living things being permissible:
https://hawramani.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/fatwa_drawing.pdf

Comment: Can I invite others to the event as I am a volunteer but there will be free-mixing?

Comment: I would assume that if you're comfortable enough to go to this professional/educational/learning event, I don't see why you should be afraid to invite others.

Comment: The fact is that I am sincere about lowering my gaze but others may not... They may see the face of the female instructor and it will be a Fitna, and I will get sin.

Comment: Looking at the face of a female isn't a sin, it's halal. Besides the hands, it's the only other part of the body that a non-mahram woman can show in public. 

We will only be judged for what we can control or are responsible for. Advise them to lower their gaze if you're concerned otherwise don't overthink it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answers!